# net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED Failed to load resource: 5000/api/activity:1

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, api, axios

i get this error when i try to fetch the data from the API, the API works fine (i test it with PostMan) but the fetching to the netside is not working

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {

    const [activities, seActivities] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/activity')
            .then(responce => {
                console.log(responce);
                seActivities(responce.data);
            })
    },[])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
              <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
              
              <ul>
                  {activities.map((activity:any) => (
                      <li key={activity.id}>
                          {activity.title}</li>))}
              </ul>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

i have seed the data to the database and it show in the postman